# difference between blastula and blastocyst

Tags: embryology

What is the difference between these 2 terms. I believe that blastocyst is for animals, but structurally is there any difference? And how would you be able to identify each?

Answer (score 2):

A blastula is a hollow ball of cells, while the blastocyst occurs slightly later in mammalian development and has a defined inner mass and an outer layer of trophoblast.